# Quoting of Queries in perls mojolicious

Tags: mysql, perl, mojolicious

I have a mojolicious app where I am using lots of queries, which are hard coded, so I am trying to differentiate between code and query by having new .sql files for each query.

I have some problems with the following query:

```
my $sql = $self->db->query(qq(
          select 
               a,
               b,
               c
          from
               table
          where 
               date_format(d, "%m") >= $month
          and
               date_format(d, "%m") <= $month
          and
                date_format(d, "%Y") >= $year
          and
                date_format(d, "%Y") <= $year
          and
                if(? = "", a, a=?)
          ), $a, $a);
```

The query above work perfect, but when I try to read it from a file my result is null.

```
my $path = Mojo::File->new('/path/to/file')->slurp;
my $sql = $self->db->query($path, $month,$month, $year, $year, $a, $a);
```

It doesn't matter if I use double quotes, single quotes or each perl function of quoting, the result is always null. When I get my params with $sth->{ParamValues} I get the right params for each call.

After coupule of hours of debugging and testing, I found out that the problem lies on the sql function "date_format" which is not called properly, but I couldn't find out why not. An alternative could be to format the time inside perl, but is not a beautiful way to handle that. I also tried to use sql variables for setting the params.

My sql file looks like:

```
          select 
               a,
               b,
               c
          from
               table
          where 
               date_format(d, "%m") >= ?
          and
               date_format(d, "%m") <= ?
          and
                date_format(d, "%Y") >= ?
          and
                date_format(d, "%Y") <= ?
          and
                if(? = "", a, a=?)
```

Comment: The query takes 6 parameters in total and i need them all, well exactly there are 3 params but they repeat themself because of the query. You have a better idea on how to rework the query? If you reffer to the second part of the question, the first "param" is the query itself.

Comment: And how do you think  if(? = "", a, a=?) should work?

Comment: This one is for the select element where I can select all from a,b,c or just for one of each. It works perfectly. How I already said the problem lies on the date_format sql function, somehow perl can't interpret it right because of the quoting.

Comment: I am confused. If a month is less than or equal 10 and at the same time also greater than or equal 10, it can only be 10. The same is true of the year. So you're basically saying _give me all rows where the date is in this month and year combination_. Doing the `DATE_FORMAT` for every row four times is not efficient at all. It makes much more sense to use `WHERE d BETWEEN ? AND LAST_DAY(?)`, and to build a date string in Perl, so that you can pass in `sprintf('%4d-%02d-01', $year, $month)` twice.

Comment: Also.. is that file slurping happening every time a route is called? You are going to disk multiple times per request to fetch a new query? That is incredibly inefficient and will not scale at all.

Comment: I tried the solution mentioned by @simbabque. It works so far, but when there are more rows with the same date, the between statement sums only one row of the day and not all of them.

Example:

| a |           d              | c   |
| - | -------------------- | --- |
|1 | 2022-09-01 10:33 | 10 |
|2 | 2022-09-01 12:00 | 20 |
|3 | 2022-09-01 16:43 | 30 |
|4 | 2022-09-28 09:31 | 40 |

`select
      sum(c)
from
       table
where
      d between "2022-09-01" and last_day("2022-09-31")
`

will result in 50 instead of 100.

Comment: You need to group by date if you want to do a `sum()`, that's an aggregate function.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. It wasn't the group because of the aggregate function sum(), the between interval handles date data as a string and cuts off the last day of the  month when you not explicitly put the timestamp on it. Mysql has an interval function which is smart enough to handle months, year, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the interval function of mysql which is smart enough to calculate the date.

For the parameters I used the sprintf function and used one variable instead of 2.

```
my $date = sprintf('%4d-%02d-01');

select sum(a), sum(b) from t1 where c between $date and $date + interval 1 month;
```